# Datepicker not working correctly in Laravel 5.7

Tags: jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating multi languages Laravel project my problem is Datepicker is not popup correctly in the English direction it is popup in the same place but top of the Datepicker not bottom and in the arabic direction every time i click it popup in different place also top of Datepicker

This is the english case : [image: English case]

And this is the arabic three cases : [image: Arabic 1] - [image: Arabic 2] - [image: Arabic 3]

Here is the app.blade.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleDirection() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Orbit | GIT</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"  ></script>

    {{--<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/ionicons.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/skin-blue.min.css') }}">
    <!-- salama new links -->
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css') }}">
    <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css') }}">

    <!-- Select2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('') }}/dashboard_files/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css">


    @if (app()->getLocale() == 'ar')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/font-awesome-rtl.min.css') }}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/AdminLTE-rtl.min.css') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/rtl.css') }}">

    <style>
        body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
    @else
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">



    @endif

    <style>
        .mr-2{
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .loader {
            border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border-top: 5px solid #367FA9;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite; /* Safari */
            animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
        }

        /* Safari */
        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

    </style>
    {{--<!-- jQuery 3 -->--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>






    {{--noty--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/noty/noty.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/noty/noty.min.js') }}"></script>

    {{--morris--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/morris/morris.css') }}">

    {{--<!-- iCheck -->--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/icheck/all.css') }}">

    {{--html in  ie--}}
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('orbitgit.ico') }}" >
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

    <div class="wrapper">

        <header class="main-header">

            {{--<!-- Logo -->--}}
            <a href="{{ route('dashboard.index') }}" class="logo">
                {{--<!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->--}}
                <span class="logo-mini"><b>O</b>GT</span>
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>Orbit</b>GIT</span>
            </a>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>

                <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
                        <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                <span class="label label-success">4</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li><!-- start message -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/user_images/'. auth()->user()->image ) }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                                                </div>
                                                <h4>
                                                    Support Team
                                                    <small>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins
                                                    </small>
                                                </h4>
                                                <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer">
                                    <a href="#">See All Messages</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        {{--<!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->--}}
                        <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                                <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
                                <li>
                                    {{--<!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->--}}
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 5 new members joined today
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer">
                                    <a href="#">View all</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        {{--<!-- Tasks: style can be found in dropdown.less -->--}}
                        <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    {{--<!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->--}}
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        @foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
                                        <li>
                                            <a rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $localeCode }}" href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($localeCode, null, [], true) }}">
                                                {{ $properties['native'] }}
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        {{--<!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->--}}
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">

                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/user_images/'. auth()->user()->image ) }}" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                                <span class="hidden-xs">{{ auth()->user()->first_name }} {{ auth()->user()->last_name }}</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                {{--<!-- User image -->--}}
                                <li class="user-header">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/user_images/'. auth()->user()->image ) }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                                    <p>
                                       {{ auth()->user()->first_name }} {{ auth()->user()->last_name }}
                                     <small>Member since 2 days</small>
                                 </p>
                             </li>

                             {{--<!-- Menu Footer-->--}}
                             <li class="user-footer">


                                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">@lang('site.logout')</a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>

    @include('layouts.dashboard._aside')

    @yield('content')

    @include('partials._session')

    <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
            <b>Version</b> 3.4.0
        </div>
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2020-2025
            <a href="https://adminlte.io">Mohamad Salama</a>.</strong> All rights
            reserved.
        </footer>

    </div><!-- end of wrapper -->

    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js') }}"></script>


    {{--icheck--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/icheck/icheck.min.js') }}"></script>

    {{--<!-- FastClick -->--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/fastclick.js') }}"></script>

    {{--<!-- AdminLTE App -->--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/adminlte.min.js') }}"></script>

    {{--ckeditor standard--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>

    {{--jquery number--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/jquery.number.min.js') }}"></script>

    {{--print this--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/printThis.js') }}"></script>

    {{--morris --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/plugins/morris/morris.min.js') }}"></script>

    {{--custom js--}}
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/custom/image_preview.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/custom/order.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/js/custom/Tafqeet.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
<script src="{{ asset('dashboard_files/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.sidebar-menu').tree();

        //icheck
        $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
            radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'
        });

        //delete
        $('.delete').click(function (e) {

            var that = $(this)

            e.preventDefault();

            var n = new Noty({
                text: "@lang('site.confirm_delete')",
                type: "warning",
                killer: true,
                buttons: [
                Noty.button("@lang('site.yes')", 'btn btn-success mr-2', function () {
                    that.closest('form').submit();
                }),

                Noty.button("@lang('site.no')", 'btn btn-primary mr-2', function () {
                    n.close();
                })
                ]
            });

            n.show();

        });//end of delete

        // image preview
        $(".image").change(function () {

            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.image-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }

        });

        CKEDITOR.config.language =  "{{ app()->getLocale() }}";

    });//end of ready

</script>


    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the create.blade.php  script code :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2').select2()

        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2bs4').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap4'
        })


        //Date picker
        $('#date').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        })
        //Date picker
        $('#dot').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        })
        //Date picker
        $('#dor').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        })


    })
</script>
```

Comment: The datepicker API has a `isRTL` option (default is false), not sure if this may help the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded old version of AdminLTE-RTL and use files of datepicker and replaced my files with downloaded files and it works now fine